# Access the if statement via base::if() in R

Tags: r, if-statement, r-package

I am coding in `R` and due to stability purposes when I have to deploy something, I call every function with the syntax `package::function(arguments)` just to avoid conflicts that as you know may happen when using a lot of packages. It helped me a lot over the years.

I know that `if` is a reserved word so technically speaking it is impossible (or at least it should be in my knowledge) for someone to define an object and name it `if`.

I am also aware that it belongs to control flow statement (which I think are a different "thing") and due to the previous consideration I am also aware that the following questions might be useless. My pure technical doubts are:

1. Why if I embrace it in back-ticks the function class returns "function" as a result?
2. Why without back-ticks I get an error? and last but most important
3. Why I am unable to access it via the usual `base::if()` syntax?

As I said, most likely useless questions but at this point I am curious about the details underneath it.

```
> class(if)
Error: unexpected ')' in "class(if)"

> class(`if`)
[1] "function"

> base::if(T) T
Error: unexpected 'if' in "base::if"
> if(T) T
[1] TRUE
> base::if(`T`) T
Error: unexpected 'if' in "base::if"
```

Comment: the double colon takes time to execute and will slow down all your code.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck The `::` was [recently changed to a primitive](https://github.com/wch/r-source/commit/5cf2557f4bd68aa863dbc3c5580c61de490c1093). Do you still notice much of a slow down?

Comment: To me it looks like a bearable cost in terms of performance, my curiosity is now about how do you avoid conflicts in big R programs  with a lot of scripts and lot packages? I mean, is there a better option to achieve the same goal of the double colon?

Comment: @MrFlick, I tried an example on R 4.0 and 4.1 and in that example it took 15% and 1% longer with double colon respectively.    `library(microbenchmark);
microbenchmark(
colon = base::transform(BOD, demand = base::sqrt(Time)),
plain = transform(BOD, demand = sqrt(Time)))`

Comment: @SabDeM, `library`  has an `exclude=` argument.  For example, I often use `library(dplyr, exclude = c("lag", "filter"))` to avoid conflicts with base.   In packages one can import and export just the objects needed.  The `conflicts()` function can be used to find all conflicts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if`-with-backticks actually returns `.Primitive("if")`

The R language definition section on ["Internal vs Primitive"](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-ints.html#g_t_002eInternal-vs-_002ePrimitive) specifies that `.Primitive` objects include

> “Special functions” which really are language elements, but implemented as primitive functions:

> {       (         if     for      while  repeat  break  next
> return  function  quote  switch

The reason that a naked "if" without backticks *or* `base::if` don't work is that the "language elements" above are treated as special cases by R's parser. Once you have typed `base::`, R's parser expects the next symbol to be a regular symbol that can be looked up in the `base` namespace. `base::if`, `base::for`, and `base::(` all return errors because *R does not expect these special elements to occur at this position in the input stream*; they are syntactically incorrect.